# Use 0.5W speaker with PAM8302A cause speaker goes hot

Tags: amplifier

I'm using PAM8302a ([datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/PAM8302A.pdf)) and an 8ohm, 0.5w speaker. It seems the amplifier is too powerful for the speaker because the speaker's back turns hot after several seconds. PAM8302a uses 5V and the speaker is directly connected to `VO_P` & `VO_N` pins. How can I keep the maximum output with good quality and don't burn the speaker?

```
   1uf                 __________
----||----|100 ohm|---|          |     /|
                      | PAM8302a |--- | |   0.5 W
   1uf                |          |----| |   8 ohm
----||----|100 ohm|---|          |     \|
                       __________
```

Comment: Almost all folks here have probably never heard of what a PAM8302a is. It is common practice to provide a link to at least a data sheet.

Comment: My guess is that you are just pumping quite a lot of energy into that puny excuse of a speaker.

Comment: Does the speaker get hot even with no signal applied to the differential inputs?

Comment: My guess is that you are pumping a 2.5W device into a 0.5W speaker, but without a datasheet and a proper schematic it is anybody's guess.

Comment: To be honest, by googling PAM8302a, first link is the Adafruit module, the second one is the datasheet, and after that many Arduino projects, you can find! I did not know to have the datasheet link for a well known IC, is that important to mark my question as 'Closing as unclear' 
Maybe I'm not familiar with question's style of this community. Sorry

Comment: What does it mean when you say you don't want to hear the speaker?

Comment: It was a typo, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PAM8302A is designed to be able to deliver 2.5 watts into a 4 ohm speaker from a 5 volt supply. A speaker impedance of 8 ohms means potentially it will deliver more than 1.25 watts but your speaker is only rated at 0.5 watts.

You are over-powering your speaker.

Comment: Can OP feed 2 V instead of 5 V to the PAM8302A? Which will probably solve the problem.

Comment: @HarrySvensson he could do that or, just limit the size of the signal fed in as an input.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. It is true, the datasheet mentioned 4 ohm, but [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2130) uses 8 ohm. I did not have the problem when I used a 3V regulator as a source for the Amplifier, but since I want to remove some component in my board, I remove that and directly connect it to V5. Also, I changed the speaker, the new one is also 0.5W and 8ohm, but seems much better. I don't feel that crazy heat anymore (Both are super cheap Chinese speakers). I'll buy 4 ohm and test it again. Thanks

Comment: @Hamed no don't buy a 4 ohm, it will get twice as hot as an 8 ohm and of course be 3 dB louder. If you want to restrict power to your speaker reduce the input signal into your PAM amplifier.